# Linker error with FFmpeg on Windows

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg, linker, windows-10

I'm trying to link FFmpeg libraries to a C program on Windows, but I can't successfully link the libraries. I downloaded the Dev archive from [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and put it into my project folder. (EDIT: The 64-bits version). The compilation works well but when I'm trying to link libraries, I get some undefined reference errors. Here is the command I'm trying:

`gcc -o .\metadata.exe .\metadata.o -L .\ffmpeg-20170628-c1d1274-win64-dev\lib\ -lavutil -lavformat -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavcodec -lswresample -lswscale -lm`

It then outputs me:

`.\metadata.o:metadata.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to 'av_register_all'
.\metadata.o:metadata.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to 'avformat_open_input'
.\metadata.o:metadata.c:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to 'av_dict_get'
.\metadata.o:metadata.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to 'avformat_close_input'`

Paths are good because if I change the -libs parameters or the -L parameter I get files not found errors. Finally, I took those libraries from the Makefile in the examples' folder.

What is the source of the error? Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

EDIT: Okay so I found what was the problem. As I'm using MinGW, it includes a 32-bits compiler. So as I downloaded the 64-bits, something was off. I tried downloading the 32-bits builds and it built and linked successfully with only -lavformat and -lavutil parameters. And to run the program I needed the DLL which can be found in the Shared build (and 32-bits of course) on Zeranoe's website. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif to include the headers?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't change a thing, I get the same error. I'm trying to build everything from scratch on a Raspberry and see if I can build it. If I do succeed, I'll try from scratch on Windows. Thanks again! :)

PS: Here's the code I'm trying to build: https://pastebin.com/07jvxMfP

Comment: The order in which the libraries are loaded or linked is also important (dependent on static or shared), as they need to ref dependencies from other ffmpeg libs.

Comment: I didn't know that! :) How do I know what order I should put the dependencies?

Comment: This is the order from a Qt Android project: -lswscale -lswresample -lavutil -lavcodec -lavformat -lpostproc -lavfilter

Comment: It still doesn't work. But I finally built FFmpeg on the Raspberry and installed it (it's the first version, it took me the whole afternoon). Now I'll be trying to build examples by hand on the RPi. Thanks for helping me! :)

Comment: I use the Odroid (similar but more powerful than the Pi) with both android and linux and also use ffmpeg with them. It's a great learning curve. Enjoy.

Comment: Great! :) So I successfully build the metadata.c example on the Pi with this command: gcc metadata.c -o metadata -lavdevice -lavformat -lavfilter -lavcodec -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lm -lz -lpthread -lx264. So I guess I'll try to build it on Win and try again. And it that doesn't work, I'll play with it in a VM or the Pi. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, how easy is it to learn to use the library versus just calling the FFmpeg binaries? And can I do more with the libraries than the binaries? Thanks again!

Comment: The CLI is much easier to use because feedback is instant, but I'm a programmer, I like to dabble and make magic happen :-) Either way, it's all trial and error. Good to hear you got it working...

Comment: Thanks you! Have a nice day!

Comment: Ok I'm coming back to you because I found what I did wrong! Please check my edit above! :)

Comment: I mainly use Linux which makes building ffmpeg so easy with ./configure and make. I believe windows has cygwin which is similar but fiddly to get used to. Nice one for getting it done. I hope you've made notes on the steps you took to get there :-)

Comment: Yes, it was way easier to build it on the Pi even though it took the whole afternoon. Building it on Windows is another thing with Cygwin or MinGW or Visual Studio, and they all work differently. Have a nice day! :)